# Pandas: speeding up a query to a large SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I have created an SQLite database containing 32GB worth of financial data (I started from csv files and then used the `to_sql` command in `pandas`). More specifically, the database has over 550 million rows and 6 columns (3 string columns, 2 float columns and a date-time column). I want to perform a simple count by group query using `pandas` but this seems to take a very long time. I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///trade_data.db') 
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) as `number_of_trades`'
                   'FROM data '
                   'GROUP BY Type ', disk_engine)
```

However, when doing this on my machine (a standard laptop) this simple query takes about 1 hour and 10 minutes. Does anyone have an idea on how to speed this up? Thanks!

Comment: As @Kathirmani says in  his answer, you could try to add an index. I'm not so familiar with SQLite ddbb, but for such a volume I would try an open source like postgres, MySQL. Pandas has nothing ti do with performance in this case. Hope it helps.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly the slow performance is mainly due to SQLite being not an efficient db? And other database formats like MySQL would improve the performance?

Comment: Well, it was not really an answer, but indeed with such a volume I'd rather go to a real database... However the query you're posting will always be a bit slow. How many types there are? An index by type will help, but I guess not much. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add index to your sqlite tables. Refer [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm)